# Function Pointer problems: passing and declaring

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

Hey i'm trying to figure out Function pointers and how to pass them around/ declare them, but i'm having a little trouble passing a pointer in my Button class constructor and setting it's member function pointer too the passed pointer.

- when i write Button(Func1) Button1 it says expected a ';'
- when i write Button(Func1);        it says no default constructor for Button
- when i write Button(&Func1);       it says  Func1 requires an initializer
- when i write Button(&Func1()) Button1; it says expression must be lvalue or function designator

What am i doing wrong?

```
void Func1(){std::cout << "This is a function\n";};
void Func2(){std::cout << "This is another function\n";};

class Button
{
private:
    void (*Func)(void);

public:
    void Activate(){ Func() ;};

    Button( void (*Function)(void)){
        this->Func = Function;};
};

Button(&Func1) Button1;
Button(&Func2) Button2;

Button1.Activate();
Button2.Activate();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code has wrong syntax:

```
Button(&Func1) Button1;
Button(&Func2) Button2;
```

It should be:

```
Button Button1(&Func1);
Button Button2(&Func2);
```

And function pointer declaration:

```
void (*Func)(void);
```

Leave without void in parameters:

```
void (*Func)();
```

**Edit**: Working example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/Zo9tE).

Comment: Button Button1(Func1); should also be legal, since the name of a function without () is actually the starting address of that function.

Comment: Yes, it's legal too. But & doesn't cause anything.

Comment: I'm glad it help you. And looking at your all questions i'm surprised about that mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like:

```
return_type (*ptr_name)(arguments);
```

It's often easiest to use typedefs to keep it as close to that as possible, too. For example:

```
void *(*f)(int);
```

can be rewritten as:

```
typedef void *ret_type;

ret_type (*f)(int);
```

this becomes particularly relevant when/if things get complex -- for example, any time you do some pseudo-functional programming, with one function returning a pointer to another function, you almost certainly want to use a typedef to keep the two straight.

Edit: You should also be aware that you seem to be trying to re-invent the Command pattern. You might want to look at (for one example) the implementation of the command pattern in *Modern C++ Design*.

Comment: void *ret_type; - wrong, it's declaration of variable not typedef!!

Comment: @Miro: Hmmm...you mean a `typedef` should actually say `typedef`? What a strange idea! :-) seriously, thanks -- corrected.